# How do I create an installation CD in Windows XP?

Tags: live-cd, cd

I keep seeing information on installing ubuntu from a live CD, but can't find any info on how to create the "live CD".  Is that information posted anywhere, or can you tell me how to do it.  I've already downloaded what I thought I'd need, but I can't seem to make it work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, it helped me.

[LiveCD - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

You can use a LiveCD to try out and/or install Ubuntu. I used it to try and finally installing Xubuntu. It can be used for Lubuntu and Kubuntu also.

To prepare your LiveCD download the iso of your choice and choose your media:

```
CD ( write once CDs are best)
USB (1GB or more)
```

You will need to burn your iso to the CD. I used [Active ISO Burner](http://www.ntfs.com/iso-burning.htm).

Put the LiveCD in your CD/DVD drive and reboot your computer. A menu is displayed asking

```
Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu
```

Selecting Try Ubuntu means you can 'Try Ubuntu' without making any changes to your computer. If you select this you should see a desktop called a "LiveCD session".

Comment: Could you summarize what the link says in case it ever gets taken down?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from a virtual machine, which would probably be easier to use as the Startup Disk Creator than to do it in a Windows machine. Either way, you'd need a blank flash drive or CD and a copy of the .iso image which you can get [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

---

### Prerequisites

- An .iso image.
- Software to create this live CD. I suggest [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).
- a flash drive or a CD. Note that some computers lack the ability to boot from a flash drive. Check your BIOS settings before making the installation media!

### Copying the Installation Files

1. Make sure that you have removed all files from your flash drive/CD, as they will be destroyed in the process.
2. Open up Rufus. Under `Device`, select your device.
3. Under `Partition Scheme and Target System Type`, select "MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI computers", which should be the default.
4. `File System` and `Cluster Size` should be set to their defaults.
5. You can label your flash drive whatever you want, it's just a name.
6. Check the box that says `Create a bootable disk using` and then select "ISO Image". Next to that, click the CD button and select the ISO you downloaded earlier.
7. Click "Start". Do not remove the flash drive/CD while it's copying the files!

All done.

### Installing the Operating System

In the target system's BIOS, make sure that "Flash Drive" or "CD" is higher on the list than "Hard Drive".
Reboot and you should now boot into the live CD. Follow the on-screen instructions to install Ubuntu.